# Listening for a change in number of elements of a ListView backed by an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView`, which uses an `ArrayAdapter`. When the number of elements is changed, I'd like to `doSomething()`. This should include instances where a `filter` is applied.

What's the most elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: you mean when the elements changed you then filter it?

Comment: No, I'd like to `doSomething()` when the size of the displayed list changes. When applying a filter, the size of the displayable list obviously changes, and so I'd also like to `doSomething()`.